# Deletar dados no MongoDB usando um parâmetro de data

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb

Estou implementando um sistema na empresa que trabalho e o sistema utiliza o MongoDB. Preciso conseguir deletar dados a partir de uma data.
EX: dados de 2020 a 2021 tudo que estiver dentro desse período de data devo excluir.

Já tentei usar o remove(), deleteMany() mais não tive sucesso, sabem como posso fazer? Obrigado pela ajuda desde já

db.rocketchat_messege.remove({_updatedAt: "2022-09-27"})
db.rocketchat_messege.deleteMany({_updatedAt: "2022-09-27"})
db.rocketchat_messege.deleteMany({_updatedAt: ISODate("2022-09-27")})

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJZWw.png)

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Artlazz, coloque o código que vc tentou com o filtro... Sabendo como vc usou o remove e deleteMany com certeza dará pra te ajudar melhor.